# .HTACCESS TLS/SSL Auto redirect disrupting normal MVC routing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https, friendly-url

I have just purchased tls cert form comodo. Prior to that I had my .htaccess file working fine. I used to have these rules in my .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I wanted an auto redirect from http to https; and because I couldn't do it myself, so my hosting company helped me add the following to the above :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

and they also commented the first line of my own like thus : `#Options -MultiViews`
The problem now is that normal page routing is no more working at the https addresses. Something that looks like this `http://www.my-site.com/somepage` now looks like `https://www.my-site.com/index.php?url=somepage` . I wouldn't have worried if not that certain settings right from the bootstraping page are not getting through to the latter.

I want to have the best of both worlds, the https redirect and my pretty url. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep `http->https` redirect rule at the top:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I got this error on the browser `This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'

Comment: Now, what would programmers do without SO and without people like you.Works like charm. A million thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Now you can change from `302` to `301` to make it a permanent redirect.